# What does "it" refer to in this John Locke text "...that Nature hath provided and left it in..."?

Tags: pronouns

> ... the "labour" of his body and the "work" of his hands, we may say, are properly his. Whatsoever, then, he removes out of the state that Nature hath provided and left **it** in, he hath mixed his labour with **it**, and joined it to something that is his own, and thereby made it his property. **It** being by him removed from the common state Nature placed **it** in, it has by this labour something annexed to **it** that excludes the common right of other men. - Locke (1690) in (Spinello, R., & Herman T., Intellectual property rights in a networked world: theory and practice, 2005)

Besides the hard time I'm having with understanding the overall Locke's quote, I am puzzled by what frequent *it*s refer to in the text. I guess they are redundant, giving me the impression that relative pronouns were not so popular in the old days of English.

Answer (score 3):

This is perhaps confusing because the "it" refers to a noun which does not appear explicitly in the text. Notice the "Whatsoever" at the start of the sentence: that means basically "any object", and that object is what's referred to by the "it"s later on. Paraphrasing:

> Any **object** he removes out of the state that Nature hath provided and left **it** in, he hath mixed his labour with this **object** and joined **it** to something that is his own, and thereby made **it** his property. **It** being by him removed from the common state Nature placed it in, **it** has by this labour something annexed to it that excludes the common right of other men.

(all the bolded words referring to the same object)

Comment: But the relevant *noun **does** appear explicitly* - it's the first word in the sentence: the pronoun ***whatsoever***. The fact that the text doesn't explicitly say what exactly that pronoun represents is incidental to the grammar as such.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Right. It appears only in pronoun form ("it" and "whatsoever"), not explicitly as a noun.

Comment: Yeah, well I'm certainly not going to wade through all the surrounding context to see whether "it" is any more precisely defined elsewhere. It's quite possible (*likely*, even) that it's actually supposed to be non-specific, because the important thing is how *anything* (of the general class of such things) is treated/analysed.

Answer (score 1):

"It" refers to the raw materials/natural resources from which goods are produced.  He's making the case that once goods have been produced, those goods properly are owned by someone, even though the raw materials may not have had a formal owner.